# JS turning a function into an object without using "return" in the function expression

Tags: javascript, object, closures

i have seen in a framework (came across it once, and never again) where the developer defines a module like this:

```
core.module.define('module_name',function(){
    //module tasks up here
    this.init = function(){
        //stuff done when module is initialized
    }
});
```

since i never saw the framework again, i tried to build my own version of it and copying most of it's aspects - especially how the code looked like. i tried to do it, but i can't seem to call the module's `init()` because the callback is still a function and not an object. that's why i added `return this`

```
//my version
mycore.module.define('module_name',function(){
    //module tasks up here
    this.init = function(){
        //stuff done when module is initialized
    }

    //i don't remember seeing this:
    return this;
});
```

in `mycore`, i call the module this way (with the `return this` in the module definition):

```
var moduleDefinition = modules[moduleName].definition; //the callback
var module = moduleDefinition();
module.init();
```

how do i turn the callback function into an object but preserve the way it is defined (without the `return this` in the definition of the callback)?

Comment: This is confusing. Functions *are* objects in JavaScript (*everything* is an object in JavaScript). What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: the callback is basically a JS module. i need initialize the module by calling the `init()` inside it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to use:

```
var module = new moduleDefinition();
```

and then you're going to get an object.

Oh, and maybe you want to declare `init` as this:

```
this.init = function() {
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this (I can only assume what `mycore` looks like):

```
mycore = {
  module: {
    definitions: {},
    define: function(name, Module) {
      this.definitions[name] = new Module();
      this.definitions[name].init();
    }
  }
};

mycore.module.define('module_name', function () {
  // module tasks up here
  this.init = function () {
    // init tasks here
    console.log('init has been called');
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what framework you're using or what requirements it places on you, but Javascript alone doesn't require a function to return anything, even a function that defines an object. For example:

```
function car(color) {
  this.myColor = color;
  this.getColor = function() {
    return this.myColor;
  }
  //note: no return from this function
}

var redCar = new car('red');
var blueCar = new car('blue');
alert(redCar.getColor());  //alerts "red"
alert(blueCar.getColor()); //alerts "blue"
```

Answer (score 0):

One more alternative  http://jsfiddle.net/pWryb/

```
function module(core){this.core = core;}
function Core(){
    this.module = new module(this);
}
Core.prototype.modules = {};

module.prototype.define = function(name, func){
  this.core.modules[name] = new func();
  this.core.modules[name].name = name;
  this.core.modules[name].init();
  // or
  return this.core.modules[name];
}

var myCore = new Core();
var myModule = myCore.module.define('messageMaker', function(){
    this.init = function(){
        console.log("initializing " + this.name);
    }
})

myModule.init();
```